# Finding the amplitude of a trigonometric function

Tags: trigonometry

I have the following function:

$$f(x)=\sqrt{3}\cos (x)+\sin(x)$$

I am trying to find what the amplitude of this function is without graphing it. I understand the formula for a cosine equation is:

$$y=A\cos(Bx-C)$$

Where A is the amplitude, meaning that $\sqrt{3}$ would be the amplitude, but that answer is incorrect. How do you get the amplitude without having to graph?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember your trig identities.

$$
A\cos(x - C) = A\cos(x)\cos(C) + A\sin(x)\sin(C)
$$

So if $f(x) = \sqrt{3}\cos(x) + \sin(x) = A\cos(x-C)$, then $A\cos(C) = \sqrt{3}$ and $A\sin(C) = 1$. If we square both sides and add them together, we get
$$
[A\cos(C)]^2 + [A\sin(C)]^2 = A^2[\cos(C)^2 +\sin(C)^2] = A^2 = (\sqrt{3})^2 + (1)^2 = 4
$$
So $A = 2$.

From this argument it should be clear that in the general case, the amplitude of  $a\sin(x) + b\cos(x)$ is $\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$.

Comment: Could you specify which trig identity is the first one?

Comment: @Pablo [Angle sum identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Angle_sum_and_difference_identities)

Answer (score 3):

The amplitude of $A \cos x + B \sin x$ is $\sqrt{A^2+B^2}$.
You can check easily by differentiating $f(x) = A \cos x + B \sin x$, which gives $\sin x = \frac{B}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}$ and $\cos x = \frac{A}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}$ and we can get the maximum value of $f(x)$.
So here amplitude is 2.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

$$\sqrt{3}\cos (x)+\sin(x)=2\biggl(\frac{\sqrt 3}2\cos x+\frac12\sin x\biggr)=\dotsm$$

Comment: I am still a bit lost, could you maybe hint the identity I have to use?

Comment: One of the addition formulae (two possibilities).

Comment: But how would you arrange the equation to match Sin(a+b)?

Comment: $\sqrt 3/2=\sin (...)$, $1/2=\cos(...)$.

Comment: It'd be sin(π/3) and cos(π/3), but I still don't see how you can translate those into 

$\frac{\sqrt 3}2\cos x+\frac12\sin x$

Comment: $\sin\frac\pi3\cos x+\cos\frac\pi3\sin x$ can be rewritten with the addition formulae. These formulae can also be used backwards.

Comment: I understand how you can rewrite the additional formula. I just don't get how you get from $\frac{\sqrt 3}2\cos x+\frac12\sin x$ to a point where you can employ the addition identity

Comment: You wriote yourself $\frac{\sqrt 3}2=\sin\frac\pi3$ , $\frac12=\cos\frac\pi 3$. Just replace and apply the formula.

Comment: I can't replace because π/3 is not used in the original equation

Comment: You're kidding? You *know* you have, really, $\cos \frac\pi 3$ and $\sin\frac\pi3$, and you can't use them?

Comment: I see it now thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use trigonometric identities, you will see that the amplitude is 2. Why? follow these lines

$f(x)=tan(\pi/3)cos(x)+sin(x)=\frac{sin(\pi/3)cos(x)+cos(\pi/3)sin(x)}{cos(\pi/3)}=2sin(x+\pi/3)$

Comment: Could you specify which trig identities?

Comment: $sin(a+b)=sin(a)cos(b)+sin(b)cos(a)$

Comment: I still a little bit confused on when you apply that identity. I get up to the part where you replace $\sqrt{3}$ by $tan(π/3)$

Comment: look at the nominator

Comment: I get it, but I would have never thought of that on my own. I guess I need to practice a lot more.

Comment: I am glad to hear that :)